# send output to file from within shell script

Tags: unix, shell

I'm creating a script for users to run. I need to redirect the output to a file I'm creating from inside the script (hostname-date).

I have all the pieces except for how to copy the output of the script from inside the same script. All the examples I can find call the script and > it into the log, but this isn't an option.

-Alex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following at the top of your script:

```
exec &> output.txt
```

It will make both stdin and stderr of the commands in the rest of your script go into the file `output.txt`.

Comment: can I use that with tee to sent it to the console too?

Answer (score 1):

`exec` in `bash` allows you to permanently redirect a FD (say, stdout) to a file.

Answer (score 0):

A shell that calls a shell.

Have the first shell create the variable (hostname-date)
and call the second shell redirecting the output to the file.